# Loading two different jquery slides for my site

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load two different things at once. I have a jquery script for the single page slide effect but also am trying to load a coda slider on one of the pages. It wont work. If i delete the slide jquery than the coda slider will work. How can I make them both work???

Comment: what errors do you get on the console? also which CMS or framework are you trying to run this on? and some code will be appreciated appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Coda Slider is a jQuery library so, there is know reason it will not work with jQuery script.
So, please check the following things:

> 1) See if jQuery lirbary is referenced at the beginning of all other
>   scripts.
>
> 2) You are using appropriate jQuery Library.
>
> 3) Your jQuery script is error free.

if every thing seems OK to you i think you better add the script that is not working with this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- The new doctype -->
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Coding A CSS3 &amp; HTML5 One Page Template | Tutorialzine demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<!-- Internet Explorer HTML5 enabling code: -->

<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .clear {
      zoom: 1;
      display: block;
    }
    </style>


    <![endif]-->

<meta charset='utf-8' />
<meta name="description" content="Codaslider : JQuery Slider Plugin" />

<!-- 
  Here is the style sheet for the Coda Slider
  You may want to "minify" this after making edits
  http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/ 
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/coda-slider.css">

<!-- This is just styling for the demo to make it a little less crowded at the top -->
<style>h1{margin:100px;}</style>

<!--
I would suggest using these for production, because of better caching

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">         
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js">  
</script>
-->

<!-- Definitely use these for development -->
<script src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- This of course is required. The full version (not .min) is also included in the js   
directory -->
<script src="./js/jquery.coda-slider-3.0.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(function(){

  /* Here is the slider using default settings */
  $('#slider-id').codaSlider();
  /* If you want to adjust the settings, you set an option
     as follows:

      $('#slider-id').codaSlider({
        autoSlide:true,
        autoHeight:false
      });

  */
});

</script> 


</head>

<body>

    <section id="page"> <!-- Defining the #page section with the section tag -->

        <header>
<div id="navbox">
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="home"><a href="#page" class="current">Home<br><span  
    class="little">you start here</span></a></div>
        <div class="about"><a href="#article1">About Us<br><span class="little">what we 
    do</span></a></div>
        <div class="gallery"><a href="#article2">Gallery<br><span class="little">a look 
    inside</span></a></div>
        <div class="events"><a href="#article3">Events<br><span class="little">planning 
    & design</span></a></div>
        <div class="contact"><a href="#article4">Contact Us<br><span 
   class="little">more info</span></a></div>
    </nav>
  <div id="socialLinks">
            <a href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#" class="pinterest">Pinterest</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkedin">LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="banner">
    <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Hi There,</h1>
    <h2>WELCOME TO MY KIDS WISH, AN UPSCALE EVENT PLANNING COMPANY SPECIALIZING IN 
     CHILDREN'S AND ADULT PARTIES, BABY SHOWERS, AND MORE!</h2>
    <h3>Our events consist of detailed party packages complete with one of a kind decor 
    , unique favors, candy buffet, Characters  etc…  Whether you are planning a Disney   
    themed party for your little one, or the most elegant Adult party, My kids wish can 
     meet your needs. Let us do all the work while you sit back with family and friends 
       to enjoy....</h3>
    </div>



</div>
</header>
        <section id="articles"> <!-- A new section with the articles -->

            <!-- Article 1 start -->

            <div class="line"></div>  <!-- Dividing line -->

 <article id="article1">
             <!-- The new article tag. The id is supplied so it can be scrolled into   
 view. -->

<div id="navbox1">
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="home"><a href="#page">Home<br><span class="little">you start    
here</span></a></div>
        <div class="about"><a href="#article1">About Us<br><span class="little">what we 
do</span></a></div>
        <div class="gallery"><a href="#article2">Gallery<br><span class="little">a look 
inside</span></a></div>
        <div class="events"><a href="#article3">Events<br><span class="little">planning 
& design</span></a></div>
        <div class="contact"><a href="#article4">Contact Us<br><span 
class="little">more info</span></a></div>
    </nav>
  <div id="socialLinks1">
            <a href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#" class="pinterest">Pinterest</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkedin">LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navborder"></div>
        <div class="articleBody clear">
            <div class="aboutusimg"></div>
            <div class="middle">
            <h1>My Kids Wish is here to create an unforgetable and unique themed party. 
  As every child has their own individual character so does each event we create. 
  Bringing a childs imagination to life is what we thrive.</h1><figure>
              <img src="images/cake.jpg" width="250" height="175" alt="cake"> </figure>

            <h1>Our parties are very detailed and will exceed your expectations. We 
  specializes in parties of all ages. We'll assist with planning special occasions so  
  that all you'll have to do is show up! Leave the planning to us and we'll take care 
  of the invitations, specialty entertainment, decorations, candy buffet, setup, and 
  clean up!</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </article>

            <!-- Article 1 end -->


            <!-- Article 2 start -->


<article id="article2">
             <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
    <div class="ribbon-front">
 <nav class="menu">
        <div class="home"><a href="#page">Home<br><span class="little">you start     
 here</span></a></div>
        <div class="about"><a href="#article1">About Us<br><span class="little">what we 
 do</span></a></div>
        <div class="gallery"><a href="#article2">Gallery<br><span class="little">a look 
 inside</span></a></div>
        <div class="events"><a href="#article3">Events<br><span class="little">planning  

 & design</span></a></div>
        <div class="contact"><a href="#article4">Contact Us<br><span   
 class="little">more info</span></a></div>
    </nav>      </div>
    <div class="ribbon-edge-topleft"></div>
    <div class="ribbon-edge-topright"></div>
    <div class="ribbon-edge-bottomleft"></div>
    <div class="ribbon-edge-bottomright"></div>
    <div class="ribbon-back-left"></div>
    <div class="ribbon-back-right"></div>
</div>

  <div id="socialLinks2">
            <a href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#" class="pinterest">Pinterest</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkedin">LinkedIn</a>
    </div>

<div class="navborder"></div>
        <div class="articleBody clear">
            <div class="middle">
    <iframe align="center" src="http://www.flickr.com/slideShow/index.gne?user_id=94896171@N07" width="785" height="500" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br /><center><small>Created with <a href="http://www.flickrslideshow.com">flickr slideshow</a>.</small></center>                
            </div>

            </div>
            </article>

            <!-- Article 2 end -->

            <!-- Article 3 start -->
```

```
                <div id="navbox3">
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="home"><a href="#page">Home<br><span class="little">you start here</span></a></div>
        <div class="about"><a href="#article1">About Us<br><span class="little">what we do</span></a></div>
        <div class="gallery"><a href="#article2">Gallery<br><span class="little">a look inside</span></a></div>
        <div class="events"><a href="#article3">Events<br><span class="little">planning & design</span></a></div>
        <div class="contact"><a href="#article4">Contact Us<br><span class="little">more info</span></a></div>
    </nav>
  <div id="socialLinks3">
            <a href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#" class="pinterest">Pinterest</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkedin">LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
</div>


                <div class="articleBody clear">
                    <div class="middle">

<div class="coda-slider"  id="slider-id">
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
    <p>Cras luctus fringilla odio vel hendrerit. Cras pulvinar auctor sollicitudin. Sed lacus quam, sodales sit amet feugiat sit amet, viverra nec augue. Sed enim ipsum, malesuada quis blandit vel, posuere eget erat. Sed a arcu justo. Integer ultricies, nunc at lobortis facilisis, ligula lacus vestibulum quam, id tincidunt sapien arcu in velit. Vestibulum consequat augue et turpis condimentum mollis sed vitae metus. Morbi leo libero, tincidunt lobortis fermentum eget, rhoncus vel sem. Morbi varius viverra velit vel tempus. Morbi enim turpis, facilisis vel volutpat at, condimentum quis erat. Morbi auctor rutrum libero sed placerat. Etiam ipsum velit, eleifend in vehicula eu, tristique a ipsum. Donec vitae quam vel diam iaculis bibendum eget ut diam. Fusce quis interdum diam. Ut urna justo, dapibus a tempus sit amet, bibendum at lectus. Sed venenatis molestie commodo.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
    <p>Nulla ultricies ornare erat, a rutrum lacus varius nec. Pellentesque vehicula lobortis dignissim. Ut scelerisque auctor eros sed porttitor. Nullam pulvinar ultrices malesuada. Quisque lobortis bibendum nisi et condimentum. Mauris quis erat vel dui lobortis dignissim.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

                </div>
            </article>

            <!-- Article 3 end -->
            <!-- Article 4 start -->
```

```
                <div id="navbox4">
    <nav class="menu">
        <div class="home"><a href="#page">Home<br><span class="little">you start here</span></a></div>
        <div class="about"><a href="#article1">About Us<br><span class="little">what we do</span></a></div>
        <div class="gallery"><a href="#article2">Gallery<br><span class="little">a look inside</span></a></div>
        <div class="events"><a href="#article3">Events<br><span class="little">planning & design</span></a></div>
        <div class="contact"><a href="#article4">Contact Us<br><span class="little">more info</span></a></div>
    </nav>
  <div id="socialLinks4">
            <a href="#" class="fb">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
          <a href="#" class="pinterest">Pinterest</a>
          <a href="#" class="linkedin">LinkedIn</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navborder"></div>


                <div class="articleBody clear">


                </div>
            </article>

            <!-- Article 4 end -->


</section>
```

#### © Copyright 2013 | All Rights Reserved | My Kids Wish

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    </section>
    </body>
```